# How to use same live id on different PCs with different keyboard layou

Tags: windows-8

I use laptop bought in USA at home (so has USA keyboard layout) and use UK based PC at office,I use the same windows live id in both the places. The problem is I cannot keep the language setting the same and at a time either windows changes to UK keyboard or US keyboard. How to set keyboard layout per PC but use the same live id? I guess this may be a valid scenario for people travelling and using different pcs in each place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from Microsoft support.

1. Add both the languages by following the section 'Type in
   different languages' in  this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/language#1TC=t1)
2. Select the needed
       language in each PC in the language bar appearing at the task bar as
       explained the doc(link).